# Harmonicity is local property

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I know that this may sound like a silly question but why exactly is harmonicity a local property. Is this reasoning enough: ?

We can for each $z\in G$ find a ball $B(z,r)\subset G$ where $h$ is harmonic. Therefore $h$ is harmonic in $G$.

Comment: Being harmonic means that the function satisfies a certain differential equation.

Comment: @mariano I know that, so it is sufficient to show that the equation is satisfies locally? Like the argument above

Comment: But you didn't make an argument. You simply stated the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, once you actually show that harmonicity in a neighborhood of every point implies harmonicity on the entire domain, you have shown that harmonicity is a local property. (In general, all differential equations are local, since the derivative only depends on the behavior of the function in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the point.)